# Overlaping Values in Conky

Tags: 15.04, conky

I have a problem regarding about my conky config. When I run it and observe it for quite a while its values and status overlap each other and I dont know what is happening. Please help.

attached picture of my dilemma
[image]

Answer (score 0):

From conky configuration file changes from `own_window_type override` in `own_window_type normal`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but when I put that my conky creates its own movable window. I dont like that. what I am after is to fix the overlaping of values in my conky config

Comment: Before http://i.imgur.com/UouRJBI.png and after modification http://i.imgur.com/QjkKgvj.png

Comment: nice looking conky.. well i might try changing my conky.. can i borrow your conky config?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0uz5itEGN87MmNKeU8zZm92MWs

Comment: @GheorgheBoghitoiu: I recommend, that you add the screenshots to your answer by [edit]ing it, because I believe, they would greatly increase its value. Also, comments may be deleted or hidden for various reasons.